# Having troubles downloading the data dump

Tags: support, data-dump

I'm having troubles downloading the Stack Overflow data dump.

I've tried both the torrent and .zip download [here](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange/v2).

The torrent goes up to 7%, the incoming data does not verify correctly, and it keeps redownloading the same chunks over and over again.

As for the direct download, it just stops after a couple of megabytes and the download is corrupt.

The comments at the bottom of the page seems to indicate that others are having problems downloading the files as well.

Any ideas? Any alternative download locations?

Comment: I've seen other reports from people having trouble but I can't find the post...

Comment: Found it: it was in the mentioned in the [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=3217412#3217412)

Comment: Also mentioned on MSE [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224873/all-stack-exchange-data-dumps)

Comment: I think you're out of luck for the current release -- it seems to be very corrupt, and we'll need to wait until they release a new, fixed, version. There is no alternative location to download this release, though you can query some if it [in the data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/). If you could use older data, you can find links to download the older torrents [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224873/all-stack-exchange-data-dumps/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was just able to download the [torrent](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackexchange_archive.torrent) from archive.org just fine.  If you were having an issue please try again.  We didn't receive a response from support but they may have fixed the glitch.

[image: Torrent]

I'm at 99.9% done with the download but all of the files are there.

Comment: Something is very strange with that torrent. It worked with the third torrent client I tried.

Comment: can you verify the data for stackoverflow site is actually the latest dump? I don't think the problem is actually fixed... data dump for stackoverflow seems to be last year's. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254271/latest-stack-exchange-data-dump-on-internet-archive-not-latest

Answer (score 6):

I've asked our developers and they think it's a problem that the Internet Archive needs to fix. I wrote to them on March 30, but I haven't heard back from archive.org. It looks like the only options right now are:

1. Wait for the next data dump, or
2. Download the [files for individual sites](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange).

I'll check with our developers to see if we can make the next dump happen sooner rather than later.